# Firebase initialization error in VueJS Project

Tags: firebase, vuejs2

first time posting here. Also quite new to VueJS, know some Angular.

I ran into an error when initializing Firebase(first time getting this error) in my VueJS project:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K38oJ.png]

That showed up briefly after click event, so I had to slow down my network to take screenshot.

- I've included `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.5/firebase.js"></script>` in **index.html**
- I also installed firebase(latest version) via **npm** with --save

And **created 2 files**: firebaseInit.js and firebaseConfig.js(which contains the api key, etc for web app):

In **firebaseInit.js**:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

const firebaseApp= 
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

and put:

```
export default { the config key value pairs obtained 
from Firebase console }
```

in `firebaseConfig.js`.

Extra info(though I don't think this is the source of the problem):

I imported firebase with `import firebase as 'firebase'` in the vue file I used firebase `auth()` and `createUserWithEmailandPassword()` in the **methods** property, but `alert()` doesn't work.

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
  name: 'register',
  data: function() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    register: function(e) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(
          user => {
            alert(`Account made for ${user.email}`);
            this.$router.push('/');
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err.message);
          }
        );

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't need to include the `<script>` tag if you're building your app with the `npm` version

Comment: Thanks, I removed it. Though, still getting that error...

Comment: I think I see the problem... nothing is importing / executing your `firebaseInit.js` file. That should be the file that exports your firebase _app_, then you can all `auth()`, etc on the app

Comment: Oh.  *facepalm* Thanks again. Though, I don't get why the `alert()` inside  `register` function isn't showing when I click the button,

Comment: Because `firebase.auth()` throws an error. You're meant to call `auth()` on your `firebaseApp` object

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your `firebaseInit.js` but since you never import or require it, is it never executed, thus resulting in a "firebase not initialized" error when you try to use the `firebase` you imported from the generic firebase module instead.

Use `export default firebaseApp` in your `firebaseInit.js` (and not firestore as you do now) and then `import firebase from 'path/to/firebaseInit.js'` for example.